# Lua scripting in redis gives error when using string.gsub as argument in redis.call()

Tags: lua, redis

I have a simple lua script like this:

```
local json = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if json == false then
    return nil
end
local newJson = string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1)
return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], newJson)
```

This works as expected.

But if I skip the newJson declaration and go straight to the:

```
local json = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if json == false then
    return nil
end
return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1))
```

Then I get this error from Go "Redigo" Redis client:

```
ERR Error running script (call to f_3dc195393616dc1f56a13d6c471e0b68b3e4c8b3): @user_script:5: ERR syntax error
```

Why is this happening? The string.gsub is just returning a string according to this page:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/gsub.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native Lua string.gsub returns 2 values. Maybe the Corona reference is not correct?

1st return value is the modified string.
2nd return value is the number of matches occured.

```
local newJson = string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1)
return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], newJson)
```

here you only pass the first return value to recis.call

whereas in the following call you would pass both return values to redis.call which causes an error.

```
redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1))
```

Try `print(string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1))`to see how many return values you really have.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful!

Comment: @Alex You can still directly pass the result without creating `newJson` by calling `redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], string.gsub(json, '"isViewed":false', '"isViewed":true', 1), nil)`

Comment: What is that nil at the end?

Comment: @Alex doesn't make sense to me. should not make a difference to your call.